# Print character amount to the file Python

Tags: python

My code pretty much asks user input and a pre made text which it prints to the .txt file. I want to add the character calculator to print into the file, not as a print. Is it possible?

```
input = input(str("Type something: "))
file = open("harjoitus.txt", "w")
file.write(str("This code is here automatically.\n"))
file.write(str(input))
file.write(str("\n",))
file.close()

with open("harjoitus.txt", 'r') as file:
    text = file.read().strip().split()
    len_chars = sum(len(word) for word in text)
    print(len_chars)
```

This pretty much prints the amount of characters as print not to the text file how I want it. Is it possible to edit this somehow that it prints the character amount straight to the file and not as a print?

Comment: change ```print(len_chars)``` to ```file.write(len_chars)```

Comment: The `print()` command is for printing something to console. If you want to write into a file, you can use `f.write()` as in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects)

Comment: @KurtisStreutker doesn't work, even if I change it to "w"

Comment: @G.Anderson I know that it does, that's why I'm asking how can I make it to print it to the file, as I don't know how to.

Comment: Are you trying to write to a new file, or append to the existing file?

Comment: I want to add it to the existing file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you append to a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706499/how-do-you-append-to-a-file)

Comment: What is `teksti`

Comment: edited 'teksti' to 'input' - Sorry I have the original version as Finnish text, forgot to translate it to English. I translate the texts to English when asking here so it's easier for you guys to read it.

It pretty much just prints the text input that you give

Comment: Note: `input = input(str("Type something: "))` is *asking* for trouble. Don't name-shadow built-ins, especially built-ins you're *actively using*! **Edit:** Ah, in your actual code it's a Finnish name that doesn't shadow anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First before you go into this appending, take a look at how many places you are calling `str()` its unnecessary most of these values are already stings and ready to be written. Also avoid variable names like `input` that have preassigned purposes in python. But to add this `count` to the end, `collections.Counter` is an option, you should open the file as `a` append. Then you can add this number to the end of your file.

```
from collections import Counter

user = input("Type something: ")
with open('harjoitus.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write("This code is here automatically.\n")
    f.write(user)
    f.write("\n")

with open('harjoitus.txt', 'r') as f:
    content = f.read()

c = Counter(content)
tot = sum(c.values())

with open('harjoitus.txt', 'a') as f:
    f.write(str(tot))
```

> ```
> chrx@chrx:~/python/stackoverflow/10.11$ python3.7 stack.py 
> Type something: vash
> chrx@chrx:~/python/stackoverflow/10.11$ cat harjoitus.txt 
> This code is here automatically.
> vash
> 38
> ```

Comment: Thank you very much. This was a new thing for me, so I didn't really know what to do. Thanks for the comment, I'll make sure to study this :)

Comment: @Koppis no prob, glad to help! Cheers :)